# How to change the version code in application created by the GameMaker?

Tags: game-maker, google-play

Code that I can not change:

[image]

Image of the error:

[image]

Inside the red square is written: `Upload failed You already have an APK or Android App Bundle with version code 1000000. Use another code.`

It turns out that I do not know how to change. At least not by GameMaker. I've been in the settings, preferences, but I do not think so at all. This tutorial below Google itself is useless. I already contacted, I sent an email to the support for more than 1 week and no response.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Global Game Settings, inside the Android/Fire tab within the General section, there is a 3-components field to set the version of the apk. 
Google Play detects automatically this setting to recognize a version from another.

[image]

Each field corresponds to version, subversion and revision number, respectively.